# In a CSV file I want to cut first 5 character out of 10 character from 3rd columnn of the file in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix

**Input File content**

```
abcde,12345,fedefg12345,aaaaaaa  
abcde,12785,feeefg12345,aaaaaaa  
abcde,12845,fezefg12345,aaaaaaa  
abcde,12995,femefg12345,aaaaaaa
```

In a CSV file I want to cut first 5 character out of 10 character from 3rd column of the file in UNIX.
Note:-Changes should be reflect in file itself.

**OUTPUT expected:-**

```
abcde,12345,12345,aaaaaaa  
abcde,12785,12345,aaaaaaa  
abcde,12845,12345,aaaaaaa  
abcde,12995,12345,aaaaaaa
```

Comment: `femefg12345` has more then 10 characters. You want to cut last 5 characters?

Comment: I want to cut first five character from third column. femefg12345 is typo. It should be femef12345

Answer (score 1):

Easy with Perl and [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS):

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -we 'csv(in    => shift,
                                 on_in => sub { substr $_[1][2], 0, 6, "" }
                             )' -- file.csv
```

See also [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr).

Comment: Thanks @choroba but i am looking in Unix.

Comment: Perl is usually installed on *nix machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quite trivially with `awk` and it's `substr` string handling command, e.g.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{$3 = substr ($3, 7)} 1' file
abcde,12345,12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,12785,12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,12845,12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,12995,12345,aaaaaaa
```

Where `-F,` sets the *field-separator* to the `','` and the `OFS` (*output field-separator*) to the `','` as well.

**Explanation**

- `-F, -v OFS=','` set the *field-separator* and *output field-separator* to a `comma`.
- `{$3 = substr ($3, 7)}` remove the first 6-characters (save substring beginning at character 7) from the 3rd field, replacing the 3rd field with the substring.
- `1` output all fields with the specified separators.

Putting it altogether provides a simple way of parsing your `.csv` file.

**note:** if the number of characters in the 3rd field can vary and you only want the last 5 regardless of number, then you can use the `length()` function to get the index of the last character (and subtract `4` to print the last `5`), e.g.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{$3 = substr ($3, length($3) - 4)} 1' file
<same output>
```

**Requested Edit Based on 7th char in 3rd field == 0**

Remember, unlike C, `awk` indexes start at `1` instead of `0`. So if you want to check if the 1st character of the last 5 shown is `0`, you need to check the 7th character. You can do that with another `substr` and then a *ternary* operator, e.g.

**New Example Data File**

```
$ cat file
abcde,12345,fedefg12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,12785,feeefg12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,12845,fezefg12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,12995,femefg12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,13001,femefg02345,aaaaaaa
```

(the last row contains your condition)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{$3 = substr($3,length($3)-(substr($3,7,1)==0?3:4))} 1' file
abcde,12345,12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,12785,12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,12845,12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,12995,12345,aaaaaaa
abcde,13001,2345,aaaaaaa
```

(I've taken the spaces out to keep the line from wrapping or scrolling)

Comment: Now I want to add one condition in it. If the 6th character is 0 instead of 1 then I want to remove first six char else  I will remove first five char. ex If fedef02345 then result should be 2345 else 12345.

Comment: OK, that is just simple arithmetic checking with `substr ($3, 7, 1) == 0`. You can even use a *ternary* operator. Give me a sec and I'll drop an example.

Comment: The [awk UserGuide - String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) are a good reference. Note those marked at the end with `'#'` are GNUawk (`gawk`) only.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @David

Comment: Really appreciate your help @David.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{sub(/.{6}/,"",$3)}1' OFS="," file

abcde,12345,12345,aaaaaaa  
abcde,12785,12345,aaaaaaa  
abcde,12845,12345,aaaaaaa  
abcde,12995,12345,aaaaaaa
```